# chrome extension - difference between refresh and hyperlink

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome

I just set up a chrome extension and got only one line in my javascript file to test it:

```
 window.alert('test')
```

When I navigate to google.com I get the alert. When I refresh the google page I get it as well. When I click on the google logo (which leads to google.com as well) I don't get the alert.

That's my problem. I want the script to be executed every single time the site is being refreshed / loaded / called.

Any ideas ? Thanks !

Comment: That doesn't reload that page (it uses Javascript)

Comment: Is there any event for this 'javascript reload' ?

Comment: That depends how you define it.

Comment: I just wanna make sure that my code is being executed as soon as the page refreshes. No matter if it's a legit refresh or a navigation through javascript.

Comment: Define "Refresh".  What if part of the page is re-rendered?

Comment: Everytime the favicon turns into a loading symbol